# What is `Train_MEml()[[method]](...)` doing?

Tags: r, function, methods

I am using the following function from github (https://github.com/nguforche/MEml/blob/master/R/MEml.R#L110).

```
MEml2 <- function(method, data, id,  resp.vars, rhs.vars, rand.vars=NULL, para,  ...){


  mod.res <- tryCatch(
{
    trn <- data[, unique(c(resp.vars, rhs.vars, rand.vars, id)), drop = FALSE]
    Train_MEml()[[method]](trn=trn, para=para, resp.vars=resp.vars, rand.vars=rand.vars, rhs.vars=rhs.vars, groups = id) 

}, error=function(e){ 
  cat("Error in the Expression: ",  paste(e$call, collapse= ", "), 
      ": original error message = ", e$message, "\n") 
  list()
}) ## tryCatch
  collect.garbage()
  return(mod.res)
}
```

I do not know what the line `Train_MEml()[[method]](trn=trn, para=para, resp.vars=resp.vars, rand.vars=rand.vars, rhs.vars=rhs.vars, groups = id)` is doing. It seems that it is calling a function. However, there is no function called `Train_MEml` in corresponding **MEml** package.

In the package, there are other functions coming with `UseMethod(method)` where corresponding method substituted here.

Q1: What is `Train_MEml()[[method]](trn=trn, para=para, resp.vars=resp.vars, rand.vars=rand.vars, rhs.vars=rhs.vars, groups = id)` doing here?

Q2: What is `Train_MEml()[[method]]` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the syntax, it appears that `Train_MEml()` returns a named list of functions, and `[[method]]` (where `method` should be a character string) is used to select a particular one. Then you can call this function by putting `(loads_of_arguments)` after it.

Indeed, `Train_MEml` is defined here: https://github.com/nguforche/MEml/blob/master/R/MEml_train.R

---

I would also like to comment about your attempt to understand what's going on.

> It seems it is calling a function. However, there is no function called `Train_MEml` in corresponding **MEml** package.

This function is an internal function, not intended to be seen or called directly by users. As you see from the NAMESPACE file: https://github.com/nguforche/MEml/blob/master/NAMESPACE, this function is not exported. If you want to access this function in your **R** session, use `MEml:::TrainMEml`.

> In the package, there are other functions coming with `UseMethod(method)` where corresponding method substituted here.

No. It is completely a different concept. `UseMethod` is used for S3 method dispatching.